# Linker parameter order for SFML and GLUT

Tags: linker-errors, glut, sfml

I was asked by someone to look into some project, where he wanted me to implement a specific feature. However, I'm unable to get the program to run, it uses both SFML and GLUT. I'm on Windows Vista with Dev Cpp and have both libraries installed and working fine when used separately. In this project though, I'm getting a lot of linker errors which are all undefined references to GLUT functions. From previous experience, I know that changing the order of linker commands would cause errors. But I just can't seem to get it right, I'm using the following order now:
-lsfml-graphics
-lsfml-window
-lsfml-system
-lglut32
-lglu32
-lopengl32

I've also tried moving the sfml down and putting glut up, I'm just unable to build. Please help.
TIA!

Answer (score 0):

SFML already includes OpenGL in its package.

Taken from the [SFML with OpenGL tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/window-opengl.php) from the main site:

> To use OpenGL, you only have to include Window.hpp : the OpenGL and GLU headers will be automatically included by it. This is to prevent you from having to use preprocessor, as OpenGL headers have different names on each operating system.